# How to trigger a container to start another container and terminate it when a REST query is passed to it?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, minikube, kubernetes-pod

i have two separate containers having docker images where one is running the REST application and the other one is running the process for downloading satellite images. **My aim is that when i click on the download button after passing the query with defined parameters in my main application, it should start the container for download and once downloaded, it should stop the container**.Currently i am able to run the container for download independently by providing all the necessary environment variables for it's docker image in it's deployment file but in the long run these variables should be coming as the parameters from the query.How can i make this happen?
Here is the current deployment file and the parameters required for running image :

```
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: back
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: back
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: 
      labels:
        app: back
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: back
        image: back:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        env:
        - name: scihub_username
          value: test
        - name: scihub_password
          value: test
        - name: CDINRW_BASE_URL
          value: 10.1.40.11:8081/swagger-ui.html
        - name: CDINRW_JOB_ID
          value: 3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data
          name: test-volume
      volumes:
      - name: test-volume
        hostPath:
          # directory location on host
          path: /back
          # this field is optional
          type: Directory
```

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/out_data \
-e scihub_username=test \
-e scihub_password=test \
-e producttype=S2MSI2A \
-e platformname=Sentinel-2 \
-e start_date=2019-06-09T00:00:00.000Z \
-e end_date=2019-06-12T00:00:00.000Z \
-e days_back=7 \
-e footprint="POLYGON((5.8664000 50.3276000,9.4623000 50.3276000,9.4623000 52.5325000,5.8664000 52.5325000,5.8664000 50.3276000))" \
-e max_cloud_cover_percentage=10 \
-e CDINRW_BASE_URL=10.1.40.11:8081/swagger-ui.html \
-e CDINRW_JOB_ID=3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6 \
ingestion
```

Comment: use a docker-client package written in the language you use

Comment: @EfratLevitan currently i am not using any language. just deploying these containers although the one with download is written in python. Which packages are you talking about and isn't there a more straight forward way of doing it within minikube?

Comment: i dont think you should rely on minikube, since you want you code to be platform-independent. search for python docker clint and use it from the controlling container (not the ephemeral one)

Comment: @EfratLevitan so how can i modify my controlling container so that when i click on the download button in webapp it creates the container using `final ContainerCreation container = docker.createContainer(ContainerConfig.builder().build());
` from `docker client ` and after completing the container stops it using `docker.stopContainer("containerID", 10); // kill after 10 seconds
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a workload like this, a better design is to deploy a job queue system like [RabbitMQ](https://rabbitmq.com/) and have two long-running containers (Deployments, since you're using Kubernetes).  One of them runs the REST server, and when it receives a request, writes the details of the request into a queue.  The second listens to the queue, pulls off messages one at a time, and does the network fetch.

Especially in Kubernetes, this approach has a couple of advantages.  You can easily build and test it without requiring Docker or Kubernetes.  If you get swamped with requests, they back up in the job queue instead of launching dozens or hundreds of containers.  If you see you have a long queue and want to do fetches faster, you can `kubectl scale deployment` very easily and run more workers.

If you don't want to go that approach, you should use the Kubernetes API to create a [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/), which can restart if it fails, isn't tightly bound to the same node, and doesn't require root-level permission on the host to launch.  You should not run `docker` commands from inside a Kubernetes pod basically ever.  (And since running `docker` commands raises the potential of rooting the whole host, you want to be very very careful about doing it from a Web server in any case.)

Comment: thanks for all the info about jobs. so i take that route i have three simple questions.
1) How can i trigger the creation of a job when i click on the download button because the main container is already running prior to that?
2) which image and container are to be mentioned in the creation of job? the one which will be doing the downloading?
3) once the job and pod is deleted after termination of container, will the data downloaded will also be lost or will it remained saved somewhere as that's what i want?