# How to trigger a container to be activated by passing a yaml file through another container having it's env variables?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml, swagger-ui, minikube

i have the main container running which runs the swagger application with open api 3.0. Now i want that when i pass a query to this swagger interface it should take the parameters in this yaml file which basically are the environment variables for the other container and it should activate that container. How can i do hat and how should develop project structure(aligning and naming of files & folders) for that?
here is the example query:

```
{
    "workflowName": "ingestion_and_preprocessing",
    "jobs": [
        {
            "jobName": "ingestion",
            "container": {
                "image": "cdi_ingestion",
                "properties": {
                    "scihub_username": "#user#",
                    "scihub_password": "#pw#",
                    "producttype": "S2MSI2A",
                    "platformname": "Sentinel-2",
                    "footprint":"POLYGON((6.3853 51.7592,7.3604 51.7592,7.3604 51.5001,6.3853 51.5001,6.3853 51.7592))",
                    "start_date": "2018-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "end_date": "2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "max_cloud_cover_percentage": "10"
                },
                "volumes": [
                    {
                        "name": "pvc-cdi-datastore",
                        "mountPath": "/out_data"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "jobName": "preprocessing",
            "container": {
                "image": "cdi_preprocessing",
                "properties": { },
                "volumes": [
                    {
                        "name": "pvc-cdi-datastore",
                        "mountPath": "/in_data"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "pvc-cdi-datastore",
                        "mountPath": "/out_data"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

here is how i am running the to-be activated docker container independently.

```
 docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/out_data \
-e scihub_username=rehans516 \
-e scihub_password=Rehan123 \
-e producttype=S2MSI2A \
-e platformname=Sentinel-2 \
-e start_date=2019-06-09T00:00:00.000Z \
-e end_date=2019-06-12T00:00:00.000Z \
-e days_back=7 \
-e footprint="POLYGON((5.8664000 50.3276000,9.4623000 50.3276000,9.4623000 52.5325000,5.8664000 52.5325000,5.8664000 50.3276000))" \
-e max_cloud_cover_percentage=10 \
-e CDINRW_BASE_URL=10.1.40.11:8081/swagger-ui.html \
-e CDINRW_JOB_ID=3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6 \
ingestion
```

i want that when i pass the above query with parameters it should run the below container but only when i want. How can i do that and that too with minikube/kubernetes?

Comment: [My answer to your question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57305863/10008173) applies here too.  Do not try to `docker run` containers in response to network requests; especially in Kubernetes; _especially_ with complicated command lines.  (The risk of getting it wrong is a remote complete host root compromise, not isolated to the container.)

Comment: @DavidMaze i am not performing `docker run`. i just gave the above code as an example for enviornment variables but i am still not clear how can i trigger one container through another using a button and a query? because that container has to download certain satellit images

Comment: Have you considered a function as a service framework?

Comment: If you don't want to set up RabbitMQ, HTTP calls between services are extremely routine.

Comment: you could talk to the kubernetes api or use one of it's client libraries.

Comment: @Thomas could you give an example?

Comment: @MarkusDresch my main application is built on using jobs and workflows so i guess might with basic stuff rather than using something complex

Comment: @DavidMaze if i push my built images to a local docker registry and then call the containers through creating jobs, would that be able to run and terminate the respective images? and could you elaborate on your statement about HTTP calls through an example?